# How to edit a scss file in django-cms?

Tags: django-cms

I have been searching all over for information on where django-cms is storing the CSS and SCSS data for my site, which I am working on localhost. When I go to edit the CSS file directly, it has no effect, so I'm wondering what needs to be done to edit those CSS files.  Obviously they have been loaded somewhere.  How can they be reloaded, or in general what is the best practice for editing the CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to do this with both the style.scss and style.css files, which seem to have the same css classes.  But even after editing both files, I had to refresh the site on my localhost a few times before I could see the changes.  Frustrating, but it does work to edit the files directly in the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

@Lawrence DeSouza At first you should mention which plugins and style frameworks you use.

If you are using some sort of a frontend framework like [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/) your should compile its css from scss separately. You can do it right on the dev server in a separate directory outside your project dir and cloned from the [official repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.3.1.zip). Normally you would only need to change variables in "/bootstrap-4.x.y/scss/_variables.scss" file. On the next step you would compile your *.css files with "npm run dist" command and then copy compiled files from "/bootstrap-4.x.y/dist" directory to your "/projectname/appname/static/css" directory. The process is well-documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup). After copying changed files to your "static" folder you should run "python manage.py collectstatic" and refresh the page. If it's not working after refreshing the page in a browser (normally it should work) - restart the server. I am  a bit biased towards Bootstrap, but the logic should be the same in your case.